# How to use int in a C# textBox

Tags: c#, textbox, int, calculator

I made a calculator that uses textboxes.

```
private void Btnrovnase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int vysledek;
        vysledek = (int.Parse(textBox1.Text) / int.Parse(textBox2.Text));
        textBox3.Text = vysledek.ToString();
```

My code looks like this but now I want to use int named `a` in it.

The question is, is there a way to put the int in `textbox1` or `textbox2`?

Comment: It is not clear. In a textbox you can write anything you like until you reach the MaxLength number of characters. Are you asking how to force your user to input only digits?

Comment: You should research data sanitization, since you are dividing two numbers into an integer which will not always happen and numbers may not even be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only digits and numbers, you can use a NumericUpDown control.

But if you want a TextBox, you can use KeyPress event:

```
private void NumericTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
  if ( !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) ) 
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

You can assign NumericTextBox_KeyPress to all desired TextBoxes.

If you want to handle things such as decimal separator you can use for example:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator
```

Like that:

```
string separatorDecimal = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;

if ( !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) 
  && new string(e.KeyChar, 1) != separatorDecimal )
  e.Handled = true;
```